# Raw sockets privilege for normal user

Tags: sockets, privileges

I have been trying to use the raw socket in my machine under windows xp sp2. since there is no admin privilege for my user i am getting error while trying to create a sock_raw socket. does anyone know the specific privilege under Active directory or group policy so that i can ask our administrator to grant me the same?

thanks in advance,
Hari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> [O]nly members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later.

You need to be a member of the Administrators group. There is no specific Active Directory privilege, you just need to be in the group.

Comment: oh, bad luck.. thanks for the answer Dean.. so as i understand when we use a packet sniffer the user needs to have the same admin privileges, right?

Comment: Packet sniffers usually work by installing filter drivers into the TCP/IP stack. However, in order to install drivers you need to be in the Administrators group, so it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: ok, so they dont use raw sockets when they work? i guess that they use PCAP libraries and i was under the impression that they also use raw sockets for their functioning.

Comment: @Hari: they **do** use libpcap, but libpcap is implemented as a socket filter driver on Windows, and as [BPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter) (and others) on Linux. libpcap does not use raw sockets (as far as I know) in any implementation. As I said, though, you still need to be an Administrator to install the filter driver (though technically you don't need to be an administrator to *use* the filter driver, once installed - I'm not sure whether libpcap lets you do that, though)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 2003 Microsoft notes this, however XP SP2 probably disables it.

***AllowUserRawAccess***

**Key:** Tcpip\Parameters

**Value Type:** REG_DWORD—Boolean

**Valid Range:** 0, 1 (False, True)

**Default:** 0 (False)

**Description:** This parameter controls access to raw sockets. If true, non - administrative users have access to raw sockets. By default, only administrators have access to raw sockets.